# CreateObject with values from JsonFile

Tags: scala, build, sbt

I have some Objects Constructor eg:

```
AM(power: String, speed: String, Height: String, position: PlayerPosition)                                       
Constructor2(motivation: String, description: String, age: Int)
```

Then I have a JsonFile that holds data needed for all constructors 
Is there a way or some library that allows me to parse the contents of the file in a way that allows me to use it for constructing the objets:
eg:

`AM(jsonParser.power, jsonParser.speed,jsonParser.Height, jsonParser.position)`

I have multiple JsonFiles and the contents are not always the same structure so I was hoping I could use a parser and have access to the data like key: Value pair.

I am quite new to Scala, I know in ruby there are ways that this can be easily achieved and I was hoping this can be done quite easily

So if my file was a json like:

```
{
  "power": "25"
  "speed": "65"
  "description": "hello"
}
```

I would be able to `data = jsonParse(jsonFile)`
then `data.speed would equal "25"`

Comment: what json library do you use?

Comment: json-spray but would be willing to use something else if there is a easy method to do it

Comment: This is pretty straightforward with `json4s-jackson` (which I personally prefer over spray). Just `parse` the JSON then `extract` the case class representing your data. Use `Option` for fields that might be missing.

Comment: You can also look into `circe`, another really nice JSON library for Scala. It has ways to infer the `Decoder` for a class, and you can easily provide custom ones for all your different constructors.

Answer (score 0):

I would introduce an intermediate format, that transforms the *JSON* to a specific `case class` and map then to the required format.

Every solution depends a bit on the library you use.

I could add an example for `play-json` if you use this library.

Comment: My team uses spray-json. I just feel that it is a bit to complicated for what I need.
In ruby json/hash is a datatype so it is quite easy to access. Was hoping Scala has something similar

Comment: @Paul check this chapter - I think that is what you are looking for https://github.com/spray/spray-json#providing-jsonformats-for-other-types